# Value of type 'some View' has no member 'analyticsScreen'

Tags: swiftui, firebase-analytics

I have added the `FirebaseAnalyticsSwift` and `FirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport` libraries to my SwiftUI project.

In my `ContentView.swift` I have `import Firebase`

However adding the following line does not work:

```swift
.analyticsScreen(name: "main_content")`
```

However this works fine:

```
        .onAppear {
          Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView,
                             parameters: [AnalyticsParameterScreenName: "\(type(of: self))",])
        }
```

What am I missing?

[image]

This should be possible: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/tree/master/FirebaseAnalyticsSwift

Comment: can you show how you were use using `analyticsScreen(name: "main_content")`, what error you were getting, and what was the objective?

Comment: Which SDK version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

For me `import FirebaseAnalytics` works

Xcode 15.1

Firebase 10.19.1

Comment: Same for me. For some reason XCode does not turn the VIewModifier purple, like it does with "padding" or "bold" but when I added BOTH FirebaseAnalytics and FirebaseAnalyticsSwift it worked for me. Just the Swift version was not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should as well:
`import FirebaseAnalyticsSwift`
That's what worked for me.